# Displaying checked/selected items as checked on edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So i have this page where the user can can select items for two different categories (Cases and Parties). When a user creates a visit(schedule) they could select item or items from the Cases category and select certain parties. Then they save the information based on the selections. When i go to the edit page of this created schedule i would like to have the checkboxes marked for items that were selected and saved during the create page. I am not sure if i am missing up the parameters passed around or what i need to show selected items.

my Create Get & Post Code (saving information containing selections)

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(Guid caseId)
    {
        var viewModel = new VisitViewModel();
        SetCaseFields(caseId, viewModel);
        viewModel.Time = _defaultVisitTime;
        AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);

    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VisitViewModel viewModel, Guid[] associatedCasesSelected, Guid[] selectedParties)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
            AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        VisitEntry dto = Mapper.Map<VisitViewModel, VisitEntry>(viewModel);
        dto.VisitDate = _timeEntryHelper.AddTimeToDate(dto.VisitDate);
        dto.CasePartyIds = selectedParties;
        dto.Cases = associatedCasesSelected;
        SetCurrentUserAndOffice(dto);
        try
        {
            _visitEntryService.Create(dto, dto.Cases);
            this.FlashInfo(string.Format(Message.ConfirmationMessageCreate, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName));
        }
        catch (RulesException ex)
        {
            ex.CopyTo(ModelState);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Case", new { caseId = viewModel.CaseId });
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This is my Edit Get & Post Method.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid visitEntryId)
    {
        VisitEntry dto = _visitEntryService.Get(visitEntryId);
        if (dto == null) return View("Error");
        VisitViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<VisitEntry, VisitViewModel>(dto);
        SetCaseFields(dto.CaseId, viewModel);
         AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);}

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(VisitViewModel viewModel, Guid[] associatedCasesSelected, Guid[] selectedParties)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
                AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
                return View(viewModel);
            }

            try
            {
                VisitEntry dto = Mapper.Map<VisitViewModel, VisitEntry>(viewModel);
                dto.VisitDate = _timeEntryHelper.AddTimeToDate(dto.VisitDate);
                dto.CasePartyIds = selectedParties;
                dto.Cases = associatedCasesSelected;
                SetCurrentUserAndOffice(dto);
                _visitEntryService.Update(dto, dto.Cases);
            }
            catch (RulesException ex)
            {
                ex.CopyTo(ModelState);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
                AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
                return View(viewModel);
            }
            this.FlashInfo(string.Format(Message.ConfirmationMessageUpdate, Kids.Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName));
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Case", new {caseId = viewModel.CaseId});

        }
```

This method loads party info:

```
IList<Party> caseParties =
            _associatedCasePartyService.GetAssignedPartiesForThisAndAssociatedCases(viewModel.CaseId,
                                                                                    _currentUser.OfficeId);
        if (caseParties != null)
            viewModel.AvailableCaseParties = caseParties;
```

This is my viewModel:

```
public class VisitViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<Party> AvailableCaseParties { get; set; }
    public IList<Guid> PartiesSelected { get; set; }
}
```

VisitForm.ascx containing fields placements:

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("Parties", Model); %>
```

Parties.ascx - which contains the row to allow checking the box and when done so and go to edit the entry the page loads with all the saved info except the checked parties:

```
 <% if (Model.AvailableCaseParties != null && Model.AvailableCaseParties.Count() > 0)
     {%>
         <div class="row">
         <fieldset>
         <legend>Parties</legend>
         <div>
                                            <%=Html.Grid(Model.AvailableCaseParties).Attributes(id => "PartiesGrid").Columns(
         column =>
           {
             column.For(party =>
             string.Format("<input type='checkbox' {1} name='selectedParties' value='{0}'/>",
                                                                                 party.PartyId, Model.PartiesSelected != null &&  Model.PartiesSelected.Count(p => p == party.PartyId) > 0 ? "checked" : string.Empty)).Encode(false).Header(string.Format("<TH><input type='checkbox' name='checkSelect'/></TH>"));

         column.For(party => party.FullName).Named(Kids.Resources.Entities.Party.EntityName);
                                                    }
                                                                  ).Empty(string.Format("No {0}", Kids.Resources.Entities.Party.EntityNamePlural))
                  %>
               </div>
          </fieldset>
     </div>
```

Comment: Could you show relevant section of your view containing the dropdown list which is problematic?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov added more code above. Thanks.

Comment: @Amina will take a look at this soon, but I think you need to shorten this to a relevant portion.

Comment: @gideon i went a head and shortened the code. Thanks