# Displaying items in dropdown list box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select, dropdownbox

I am trying to display in a dropdown list box a list of 'scheduled visits' based on previous entries. I am able to gather the information but when i display it the dropdown list box turns into an input box and non of my information that i want are being displayed. The format in which i would like my items to be displayed is by : 10/2/2012 - At School.

Here is what i have for my code:

This is where i gather the info of the visit - date and place

```
public JsonResult GetVisitDetails(Guid visitEntryId)
    {
        var model = new VisitDetailModel();
        VisitEntry visitEntry = _visitEntryService.Get(visitEntryId);
        if(visitEntry == null)
        {
            model.Message = string.Format(Message.NotFoundMessage, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName);
            return Json(model);
        }
        model.VisitEntryId = visitEntryId;
        model.VisitTypeId = visitEntry.VisitTypeId;
        if (visitEntry.VisitType != null)
            model.VisitType = visitEntry.VisitDate.ToShortDateString();
        return Json(model);
    }
#region Nested Type:VisitDetailModel

    public class VisitDetailModel
    {
        public Guid VisitEntryId { get; set; }
        public short VisitTypeId { get; set; }
        public string VisitType { get; set; }
        public string VisitDate { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
```

This is what i have in my AddToViewModel:

```
 var visits = _visitEntryService.FindAllForCase(viewModel.CaseId, _currentUser.OfficeId).Where(v=>v.VisitDate <= DateTime.Today.SetToMaximumTime()).OrderByDescending(v=>v.VisitDate).ToList();

        visits.Insert(0, new VisitEntry());
        viewModel.Visits = visits.ToSelectList("VisitEntryId", "Display", viewModel.VisitEntryId.ToString());

        if(viewModel.VisitTypes.Count() == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("",string.Format("No active {0} entered.", Kids.Resources.Entities.VisitType.EntityNamePlural));
```

My .ascx page to show dropdown:

```
<div class="row">
<%:Html.EditorFor(m=>m.VisitEntryId) %>
<%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Visits) %>
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.VisitEntryId) %>
```

My viewModel:

```
 [LocalizedDisplayName("VisitEntry", NameResourceType = typeof(VisitActivity))]
    public short? VisitEntryId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [DropDownList(DropDownListTargetProperty = "VisitEntryId")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Visits { get; set; }
```

Any information of why i am not able to display a dropdownlist would be helpful.

Comment: You want a dropdown list with the viewmodel's message and date property in the options right? But in your ascx you're doing `EditorFor`! Gather the right information into a select list and use `Html.DropDownFor`

Comment: @gideon - you are a life saver! Thanks for helping me notice this. I actually looked in the ascx and i had the labels of labelFor and EditorFor switched in places and i fixed that and it worked. Thanks for you help in indirect way. If you want make it an answer and i will mark it for you.

Comment: You're welcome. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ascx you're doing EditorFor on `model.VisitEntryId` which is an `int`

You need a `Html.DropDownFor` for a drop down list.

Your `model.Visits` is a SelectList and I'm guessing you should do:

```
<%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.VisitEntryId) %>
<%:Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Visits) %>
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.VisitEntryId) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Also now that i figured that out - do you know how i can go about prefiling fields based on the selected item in this dropdown? Lets say i selected Visit: 5/4/2012 - At School. Below the date field will change from the default of today's day to the selected date 5/4/2012 and the Visit type will be: At School. Any places where i can look for ideas or examples?

Comment: @Amina Do you want to do it on the client, which would involve changing the fields with javascript, or doing it on the server will mean posting the page to the server and dishing out the right values.

Comment: Thanks for the help i actually got it answered after posting as a question. Thanks though. But i do have another question if you can take a look and maybe share any insight. I know it looks cumbersome but i thought i would post as much code as possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700755/displaying-checked-selected-items-as-checked-on-edit-page