# object, Object Msg from javascript trying to fill dropdown based on first dropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list which contains a list of visits which are displayed like so: 
*`5/3/2012 At School`* Below this dropdown list are A Date field and a visit type dropdown list. I would like to populate these fields based on the first dropdown list. so for this example the date field will be filled with `5/3/2012` and the visit type will be: `At School`

I am using javascript to use it but i am having an error window saying [object Object].

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var durationRowVisibilityCheck = function () {
    var disableDuration = $.trim($("select#UnableToVisitReasonId option:selected").text()).length != 0;
    var $durationRow = $("#visitDuration");
    if (disableDuration) $durationRow.hide(); else $durationRow.show();
};

$(function () {
    durationRowVisibilityCheck();
    $("select#UnableToVisitReasonId").change(function () {
        durationRowVisibilityCheck();
    });
    $("#VisitEntryId").change(function(e) {
        var visitEntryId = $("#VisitEntryId.option:selected").val();
        if (visitEntryId != '<%=Guid.Empty %>')
            GetVisitDetails(visitEntryId);
    });
});
function GetVisitDetails(visitEntryId) 
{
    $.ajax({
            url: '<%=Url.Action("GetVisitDetails", "VisitActivity") %>' + '?visitEntryId=' + visitEntryId,
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(json) {
                populate(json);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr);
            },
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json"
        });
    }
function populate(data) {
    $("#ActivityDate").val(data.VisitDate);
    $("#VisitTypeId").val(data.VisitTypeId);
}
```

Get Details method:

```
public JsonResult GetVisitDetails(Guid visitEntryId)
    {
        var model = new VisitDetailModel();
        VisitEntry visitEntry = _visitEntryService.Get(visitEntryId);
        if(visitEntry == null)
        {
            model.Message = string.Format(Message.NotFoundMessage, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName);
            return Json(model);
        }
        model.VisitEntryId = visitEntryId;
        model.VisitTypeId = visitEntry.VisitTypeId;
        if (visitEntry.VisitType != null)
            model.VisitType = visitEntry.VisitType.Description;
        model.VisitDate = visitEntry.VisitDate.ToShortDateString();
        return Json(model);
    }

    #region Nested Type:VisitDetailModel

    public class VisitDetailModel
    {
        public Guid VisitEntryId { get; set; }
        public short VisitTypeId { get; set; }
        public string VisitType { get; set; }
        public string VisitDate { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
datatype: "json"
```

with:

```
dataType: "json"
```

or completely get rid of it because jQuery is smart enough to use the response `Content-Type` header from the server and automatically parse the response for you.

Also remove:

```
contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

You are not sending any JSON to the server. You are sending a normal request.

So, here's how to adapt your `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetVisitDetails", "VisitActivity") %>',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: { visitEntryId: visitEntryId },
    success: function(json) {
        populate(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr);
    }
});
```

Because I have specified GET verb for the AJAX request (which is the correct verb to be used for retrieving data from the server), you need to adapt your `GetVisitDetails` controller action so that it sends JSON over GET which is not allowed by default:

```
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also the following selector seems wrong to me:

```
var visitEntryId = $("#VisitEntryId.option:selected").val();
```

Try directly retrieving the selcted value of the dropdown in the `.change()` event handler:

```
$('#VisitEntryId').change(function(e) {
    var visitEntryId = $(this).val();
    if (visitEntryId != '<%=Guid.Empty %>')
        GetVisitDetails(visitEntryId);
});
```

Comment: I just tried with your suggested changes and i still get the same window message [object, Object] not sure why.

Comment: Checkout your javascript console (In FireFox or Chrome). It will give you a far more meaningful error message than the Internet Explorer.

Comment: its telling me it is a networkerror: 500.... and http://..../GetVisitDetails?visitEntryId=undefined&_=# -- so from what i understand it is saying that it isn't holding a value for visitEntryId yet?

Comment: Yeap, this seems to be the case. The `visitEntryId` javascript variable doesn't seem to have any value. I suspect that the following selector is wrong: `$("#VisitEntryId.option:selected").val();`. Try like this: `$(this).val();`.

Comment: U ROCK! That was it (.) took it out and worked perfectly. Thanks soo much for all the help and explaining.

Comment: There is another issue i am having trouble with and wondering if you might help with it. Regarding checking the check box of items on a create page and then going to the edit page - the selected items are not checked.

Comment: I think you should start a new question about this. And of course show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Already have :D And i thank you for any help or tips in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700755/displaying-checked-selected-items-as-checked-on-edit-page